# Geometric Inertia Action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $Q_p$ and $K'/K$ a totally ramified Galois extension
with Galois group $G$.  For $g\in G$ and any scheme $X$ over $O_{K'}$, write 
$X_g$ for the base change of $X$ along the automorphism of $Spec(O_{K'})$
induced by $g$.

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth and proper scheme over $Spec(O_{K'})$
whose generic fiber descends to $K$.  By Galois descent, there is a "semi-linear" action
of $G$ on $X_{K'}$, i.e. for each $g\in G$ a $K'$-morphism

$$g: X_{K'}\rightarrow (X_{K'})_g$$

which is compatible with change in $g$ in the obvious way.

My question is:

> When does this semi-linear action of $G$ on $X_{K'}$ extend to $X$ over $Spec(O_{K'})$?

Actually, I am really only interested in the following weakened version of the above question:

> When does the semi linear action of $G$ on $X_{K'}$ induce a (linear) action of $G$
>   on the special fiber of $X$?

Certainly a positive answer to the first question implies a positive answer to the second one, since the projection map $X_g\rightarrow X$ is an isomorphism on special fibers over the residue field, since $K'/K$ is totally ramified.

Note that $O_{K'}/O_K$ is NOT etale, so etale descent does not apply here (i.e. the existence of such a semi-linear $G$ action on $X$ does not imply that $X$ admits a descent to $Spec(O_K)$.)

Here is an example of when one does get the kind of "geometric inertia" action I am seeking: Let $X$ be an abelian scheme.  Then the $K'$-maps $X_{K'}\rightarrow (X_{K'})_g$
extend to maps $X\rightarrow X_g$ by the Neron mapping property.

Comment: Bryden, in the absence of an affirmative answer to question 1, what does question 2 mean? It doesn't seem to make sense unless the first question has an affirmative answer (in which case the 2nd does too, as you note).  That is, please define "induce" in the 2nd question. Is the motivation to give a geometric interpretation for some induced action on some cohomology, or more generally is there a specific application you have in mind which may guide the search for suitable hypotheses for the first question? 

Comment: Thnks, Brian.  What I had in mind for q. 2
is the existence of a smooth and proper $O_{K'}$-scheme $Y$ with finite flat maps $Y\rightarrow X$ and $Y\rightarrow X_{g}$ such that "pullback and trace" on crystalline cohomology of special fibers coincides with the action on de Rham cohomology of generic fibers after extending scalars to $K'$ and making the usual identification of dR and crys cohomology (after extending scalars).  So yes, the motivation is to see a $G$-action on crystalline cohomology of smooth and proper schemes given the "pot crys" condition on etale coh of generic fiber descent 

Comment: Can I use the old trick of "closure of graph of generic fiber morphism in $X\times X_g$" and then Gruson-Raynaud to flatten, if needed?

Comment: The flattening will generally introduce proper maps, not finite maps. Asking for $Y$ to be *finite* flat over $X$ as well as smooth over $O_{K'}$ is asking for too much in general. It would be nice if there were some geometric interpretation of the functoriality in the generic fiber; hopefully someone will have a useful suggestion for the tame case you ask about. Ramified Weil restriction tends to destroy properness. 

Comment: This is perhaps too restrictive for general applications, but taking the closure of the graph of g gives a birational map Y -> X which is an iso generically, and has exceptional locus ruled by rational curves (a theorem of Abhyankar; see end of Kollar's RC book). In particular, if the special fibre of X has no rational curves, then the map extends (which proves the Neron property for abelian schemes, in particular).

Comment: Abhyankar says that each irreducible component of the exceptional locus of $Y\to X$ is ruled over some closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$, I don't think $Z$ is necessarily rational (blow-up $X$ along a non-rational closed subscheme). But if the special fiber of $X$ is not unirational, your argument shows that it is birational to the special fiber of $X_g$. 

Comment: Sorry for the stupid terminology, but when I said "exceptional locus is ruled by rational curves" I meant the exceptional divisor in Y, not the locus in X being blownup! Maybe the clearer thing to say is that each fibre of Y -> X is covered by rational curves...